# Breezejs, angular 2 and OData

Tags: angular, odata, breeze

I couldn't figure out what is correct way to make angular 2, BreezeJs and OData to work together

I followed instructions from this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/breeze-bridge-angular2

Also I added link to the OData library.

and my code for initializing OData adapter look like this:

```
config.initializeAdapterInstance('dataService', 'webApiOData', true);
    this._em = new EntityManager('http://localhost:7248/api');    
    this._em.fetchMetadata((schema) => {
      console.log('schema', schema);
      var collectionPointType = this._em.metadataStore.getEntityType("ClientBrowse");
      (<any>collectionPointType).setProperties({ autoGeneratedKeyType: AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity });
    });
```

but unfortunally it didn't work.

What I have found is that breezejs is trying to resolve library OData in function `__requireLibCore(libName)`, it looks in `global.window` but this variable is undefined.

I'm not sure how does global.window initialize, but seems it should be link to global window object. I guess because of some angular 2 isolation it doesn't have direct access to window.

How can I overcome this problem? For sure one of the solution is make monkey patch but I'm doubt it is way to go.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I already had imported datajs. still global object seems like an empty object..  Can someone throw a light how do I ensure right value to global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the datajs dependency. The Breeze OData adapters require datajs.

`npm install datajs --save`

Then add it to your systemjs.config.js

`map: {
      ...
      'datajs': 'npm:datajs'
    },`


    `packages: {
      ...
      'datajs': {
        main: 'index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }`

Then import it in your application, so it gets loaded.

`import { config } from 'breeze-client';
import 'datajs';`